# How to enable LOGging of all internal SQL cmd's of the Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, logging, adb

In my learning process I want to focus on next moment: EXACTLY WHICH inside the Android/phone firmware? framework? sys.Libs? SQL commands are being generating in order to process the program code of the end-user's software.
Pure example which I MUST to understand and to figured it out right now - HOW, with using of which exactly SQL commands inside the Contact Provider is running the following program code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
try (Cursor cursor = resolver.query(uri, PROJECTION, null, null, null)) {
.....
}
```

Simply speaking: in the Console/Logcat of the Android Studio I want to find out something like that:
"SELECT ... FROM phone_lookup INNER JOIN ... ON ... WHERE ... ORDER BY ...."
I am using official emulator bundled with latest Android Studio: Pixel_3a_API_30_x86.avd "smartphone" - so it should not even be difficult to use root commands in order to achieve this goal. Right now I can't get it. I've tried next calls:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteLog VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteStatements VERBOSE
adb shell setprop db.log.slow_query_threshold 0

                   and next:
adb root
adb shell stop
adb shell start
```

No results. Thus my question is - how and what and where I must use/call/set/create/delete in order to SEE ALL internal SQL commands which are being executed/generated inside the Android's body - inside ALL its internals libraries/plugins/etc. In other words, inside that everything what creates the whole Android's work environment on the phone for the end-user's software.

Comment: There is no requirement for any app, including pre-installed ones, to log SQL anywhere that you can see it. In fact, if they did that in production code, that would be a bug.

Comment: Stop-stop. but we are talking about the emulator! About the image of specially prepared AOSP system! About the Developer's phone qemu image!!! In case if I will download ALL android's sources - I will definitely find in them lines with similar logic: LOG.info("SQL cmd:" + cmd); Thus I am talking about such "specially prepared" sources.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.java
```

Comment: PROOF:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.java
```
if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
    if (Build.IS_DEBUGGABLE) {
        Log.d(TAG, sql + " with args " + Arrays.toString(sqlArgs));
    }........
``` And this file full of such lines. So we definitely for sure can somehow include the output of their contents in the studio's console. But how exactly?

Comment: I would expect them to use code shrinking (e.g., D8), and so your `Log.d()` call will only exist for builds where `Build.IS_DEBUGGABLE` was `true` at the time of compilation. I would expect that to be `false` for the code that was compiled into stock emulator images. You could certainly look to compile the OS yourself and arrange for `Build.IS_DEBUGGABLE` to be `true`, then package that OS into an emulator image, if you wanted.

Comment: So you want to say that Google's stock emulator images ARE in fact absolutely non-debuggable and useless from developer's point of view????

Comment: App developers use the emulator to debug their own apps and can use stock emulator images for that purpose. OS developers use the emulators to debug their OS changes, but they will be preparing custom emulator images for that purpose.

Comment: If someone who reads this question and the correspondence above - suddenly will understand that it has data about - how to download the image of an emulator with android for which the full debug mode is enabled, all the conclusions of the internal debug information of the android code itself are allowed for output in the log - I beg you - let me know!
I do not have the opportunity to collect such an qemu image itself, and for the training I have to see these SQL requests to understand - and what really works and how it works there. Documentation does not speak almost nothing about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as usual - if you want to do something - do making it only by yourself)))

```
try (Cursor cursor = resolver.query(uri, PROJECTION, null, null, null))
```

if in this command line to put in the last argument 100% error string - for example "LIKE bananas" - on the execution stage we will get an error "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "bananas": syntax error (code 1)"
with corresponding staсktrace which will include also and the full SQL command - in which that error was found.
Thus we can rather easily to get the knowledge - by WHICH EXACTLY SQL request a particular URI request is being made. And it will work on real phones!!! And so we can easily understand - and why suddenly we do not have an access to a particular data column, which seems to be present in the results of the query(according to online HELP for devs), but for some reason on certain models of phones they do not. And now it becomes easier to understand - and how you can rewrite your request, on the basis of "stacktraced exactly SQL" as it a reference - but with a guarantee of obtaining the necessary data as a result of its execution!

Answer (score 0):

When using these props:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteLog VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteStatements VERBOSE
adb shell setprop db.log.slow_query_threshold 0

                   and next:
adb root
adb shell stop
adb shell start
```

You shall see the result by doing 'adb logcat' and then invoking the code flow on your device. The queries will be visible in the logs.